# Is it possible to approximate a convex function with strictly convex functions?

Tags: convex-analysis

Can any convex function on a bounded interval be approximated uniformly by a sequence of strictly convex functions?

Comment: What do you mean by an approximation? How would you approximate $f=1_{\{0\}}$ on $[0,1]$?

Comment: @copper.hat: This function is already strictly convex (I assume you mean the function with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) = \infty$ for $x \ne 0$).

Comment: @gerw: I meant the standard characteristic function which is zero outside of the specified set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take your existing sequence and add $\frac1n x^2$?

Comment: I did that with a line and it worked but then I thought there could be issues with mor complicated behaviour, like when we have piecewise defined functions, let me think maybe I was overthinking it. Like, I am sure sum of convex is convex, but is it strictly convex if one of the addends are strictly convex?

Comment: Yes it is I just proved it I think you are correct then thank you!